# Inherited entities in many-to-one relation

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

Example structure of data in DB:

- `configurator_element`:

  - `id`: 1, `name`: Small set, `inheritsFrom`: null, `features`: ["Feature 1", "Feature 2"]
  - `id`: 2, `name`: Medium set, `inheritsFrom`: 1, `features`: ["Feature 3"]
  - `id`: 3, `name`: Large set, `inheritsFrom`: 2, `features`: ["Feature 4", "Feature 5"]

I would like to create, on an ORM side, a mechanism that allows to automatically fetch `Element` object with all inherited features.

Thus I would like to fetch `App\Entity\Configurator\Element` by ID `3`, aby automatically obtain the entity as below:

- `id`: 3
- `name`: Large set
- `features`:

  - "Feature 1"
  - "Feature 2"
  - "Feature 3"
  - "Feature 4"
  - "Feature 5"

Currently, I did it in my controller using:

```
$features = [];
$inheritance = $element->getInheritsFrom();

while ($inheritance instanceof Element) {
    $features = array_merge($features, $inheritance->getFeatures());
    $inheritance = $inheritance->getInheritsFrom();
}

$features = array_merge($features, $element->getFeatures()->toArray());
$element->setFeatures($features);
```

My entity class:

```
namespace App\Entity\Configurator;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="configurator_element")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Configurator\ElementRepository")
 */
class Element
{    
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var Element|null
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Element", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $inheritsFrom;

    /**
     * @var Feature[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="element")
     */
    private $features;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

features are array collection,
Instead of using setFeatures, you can use addFeature, removeFeature. so you will not need to merging array, u can add a feature in the while loop.
also in the feature entity you can add inherit

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Element")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="element_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $element;
```

in controller:

```
 $features = $this->em->getRepository(App\Entity\Feature)->finAll();
 foreach($features as $feature)
 {
     $elemet->addFeature($feature);
 }
 $this->em->flush();
```

Comment: It's not an answer to my question. I would like to configure the ORM in such way to automatically fetch inherited features.